# My problem is that I have to loop only unsuccessful requests 3 times but while controller is looping for successful requests also in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Below code is in While controller
${__jexl3(${__jm__While Controller__idx} < 3 && "${responseCode}" != "200",)}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM85M.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E4GS.png)

Above is in Regular Expression extractor

Result: It is looping 3 times for successful requests also but I want to loop only for failed requests and for success requests it should execute once
Thanks for in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your [regular expression extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter) configuration is not correct, you need to apply it to `Response Code`, not to the `Body`

[image]

With your current configuration it extracts first numeric value from the response body and [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is not there, it's a special [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header)

Comment: I need  to loop through all the values of csv file by a thread and if the requests fails then retry 3 times, so how to get values from csv

Answer (score 0):

Following another solution with a [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller), [If Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller), and [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) (FCA) controllers.

[image]

1. Add the following into the While controller

```
${__groovy(${__jm__WC__idx}.toInteger() < 5)}
```

2. Add the request and two If controllers below them with Flow Control Action elements as shown in the figure
3. Add the following into the first If Controller

```
${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

4. Select *Break Current Loop* in the FCA element
   [image]
5. Add the following to the second If Controller

```
${__jexl3(!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok})}
```

6. Set the FCA to Go to the next iteration of the next loop

If you want to do something else, in addition, to retry, Set pause in the FCA element, add a JSR 223 element inside the FCA and include the actions. For example, I wanted to log the user name of the failing requests and retry.

```
String username = vars.get("username")
int current_loop_count = vars.get("__jm__WC__idx").toInteger()

log.warn("Attempt# ${current_loop_count.next()}  $username ")

current_loop_count.next()<5?:ctx.getThreadGroup().getOnErrorStartNextLoop()
```

Comment: I need  to loop through all the values of csv file by a thread and if the requests fails then retry 3 times, so how to get values from csv

Comment: 1. Your while controller will have to check the iteration count only 2. Add an IF controller after the request, within the while controller, check the success of the request. 3. Add Flow Control Action controllers to IF controllers to break from the current loop if it is successful. This will ensure you will retry for at least 3 times if it fails and exist early if it passes

Comment: Set the sharing mode of the **CSV Data Set Config**  (_if you are using_) controller to [Current thread] (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to allow all the values to be consumed by each thread.